# While loop and Strings

Tags: javascript

```
Var randomLetters = "ljhgfdza";
Var randomString = "";
```

Now I'll have to add elements in the first variable to the second Randomly
Using the while loop, and `Math.floor(Math.random() * random letters.length)`

I am having a problem at my 
"While (condition)"  what should it be?

Comment: show us what you have. We aren't going to just code the solution for you. Edit your question to include your code.

Comment: We can't know what the requirements are. Do you have to keep adding until the strings have the same length? Some fixed length? Until all characters are used? Some other condition?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will be enough for you:

```js
const randomLetters = "ljhgfdza";
const returnRandom = (randomString) => {
  const arrString = [...randomString].sort((a, b) =>{
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
  }).join("");
  console.log(typeof arrString,arrString);
}
returnRandom(randomLetters);
```

but... in this case `sort` method is not that random as you think. [This link will tell you why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array). I would do this with `reduce()` or `map()`, both are described in link above.

Comment: Please explain why I was downvoted so I can improve my answer.

Comment: please review this code u'll understand

var i = "";

var x = "ghtyvbnm";

while (x.length < 6) {

 console.log(x += i);

Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
}

Answer (score 0):

To flat out answer your question, you can use:

```
while(randomLetters.length > 0){
```

Then when you use a letter from randomLetters, you delete the letter and the length is now 1 less.